# Vs Code debugging Blazor WASM standalone

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, blazor

I am trying to debug blazor wasm application using Visual Studio Code, and tried this method from documentation [Debug ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

So I checked got nuget DevServer Package and VS Code Extensions that are needed that is C# for Visual Studio Code Extension and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.VSCode.BlazorWasmDebuggingExtension.

Also I have my launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Blazor.Wasm": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and VsCode launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [     
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Debug Blazor Web Assembly in Chrome",
            "type": "blazorwasm",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "https://localhost:5001",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

And in result I have an error message like bellow.

[image: Error]

But I see webpage has been started, i can go to https://localhost:5001 and it works, but when i put a breakpoint it is marked as unload, like debugger is not loaded or working at all.

What can be the problem of this?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, but still looking though

Answer (score 2):

the fix has not been published yet.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45257
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45257#issuecomment-1357128650

---

This problem does not happen in **VS2022**.

---

In **VS Code** the way to debug is with chrome devtools as follows:

Launch the Blazor site from console

> dotnet run

> "chrome-path\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir="**user-data-root-path**\AppData\Local\Temp\blazor-chrome-debug" schema:// localhost:**port**/

And now in chrome: **shift+alt+D**.

Then debug blazor in chrome devtools at **source tab** and search your code in **file://**.

Then add a breakpoint and inspect in devtools of chrome.

---

#### Update on 2023-02-02

blazorwasm-companion.launchDebugProxy v1.1.3 has been released today (2023-02-02) and resolves the issue.